# How do I reuse TcpClients in synchronous blocking mode?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, task, tcpclient

I have a tcpclient that connects to a backend system sending xml queries and receiving xml responses.

The backend requires that the client logon and set some environment settings before any querying can take place. This is an expensive operation so it makes sense to create the tcpclient and keep it open for repeated queries.

The backend I'm told is optimised for handling many connections and for performance reasons I'd like to have numerous tcpclients connecting.

The queries are in the form of a list which contains thousands of items.

My question is how best to create a group of reusable connected tcpclients so I can execute a number of simultaneous requests from the list (say 10 at a time), what pattern would suit this scenario and are there any examples I can learn best practice from?

Currently it just executes them one by one using a single service which encapsulates the connection and logon process.

```
QueryService service = new QueryService(server, port, user, pass, params, app);

foreach(var item in queries)
{
    service.ExecuteRequest(item);
}

service.Disconnect();
```

Comment: have you tried using async method of tcp client within a parallel foreach loop ?

Comment: As mentioned in the title, the tcpclient is in synchronous blocking mode. Each query must send an end sequence before the backend will send the response. I'm not sure if I can do aync reads and writes on the underlying sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a *[thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)* or *[Object pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)* pattern. Basically, you can create a pool of `Service` objects and then when any element (function or object) of client application need to access the service - it can just refers to the service object based on some criteria.

To make this successful, you must have a request should be *state-less* so that when an arbitrary service object is selected for making a request to some server - the history should not create a problem.

Comment: An object pool seems like it might be a good fit, I may have some issues around making the requests state-less though so will investigate further, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I implemented an object pool pattern and it works a treat, many thanks for the pointer.